# What is the meaning of a double dot within a square bracket in C++

Tags: c++, windows, c++11

In the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\OleAuto.h`, I found the following code that I do not know how to interpret:

```
WINOLEAUTAPI SafeArrayAccessData(_In_ SAFEARRAY * psa,
_Outptr_result_buffer_(_Inexpressible_(psa->cbElements * 
product(psa->rgsabound[0..psa->cDims-1]->cElements))) 
void HUGEP** ppvData);
```

Note the double period within the square bracket. Is that a new operator in C++?

Comment: It seems like a twisted combination of SAL expressions and probably undocumented compiler intrinsics.

Comment: It sure isnt listed here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence . This site is quite thorough otherwise

Comment: I'll bet that `_Outptr_result_buffer_` is a macro, and the argument is never seen by the compiler. (If it were, it would be rejected as a syntax error.)

Comment: @KeithThompson is right. `_Outptr_result_buffer_` ultimately expands to nothing in normal compilation. The macro is used by static analysis tools.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It appears to be a SAL annotation used to tell the static analyzer that the size of the buffer is too complex to represent using ordinary annotations:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159527.aspx

It doesn't have to contain valid syntax, but what it contains is probably meant to succinctly illustrate to a human reader how the size of the buffer could be calculated.

If I'm to interpret it myself, I'd guess it means what the following code would yield:

```
DWORD CalculateInexpressibleSafeArrayDataSize(SAFEARRAY * psa)
{
    DWORD cbSize = psa->cbElements;
    for (int i = 0; i < psa->cDims; i++) // product()
        cbSize *= psa->rgsabound[i]->cElements;
    return cbSize;
}
```

Comment: And SAL is supposed to "reduce C++ defects". By writing nonsense inside hardly documented intrinsics.

Comment: @gd1: My guess is that SAL was added to that function long after it was prototyped and implemented, and then the prototype of the function couldn't be changed or removed due to backwards compatibility requirements. In general though, SAL is truly excellent and if you find declarations in your own code that cannot be sanely marked-up with SAL, that's a good indication that you should rethink what you did.